# Recursion Tree Method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

Given Equation: `T(n) = T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n^2`

Model of Tree:

```
              T(n)                 -- Level 1
             /    \
       T(n/4)       T(n/2)         -- Level 2
        /   \       /    \
 T(n/16)  *T(n/8) T(n/4)  *T(n/8)  -- Level 3
```

From Lecture of MIT Algorithm Class: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whjt_N9uYFI

Minute: 38:53

Question: How, What and Why 3rd level becomes n/8 ? What is the explicit equation to create recursion tree?

This isn't the homework question by the way.

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original tree is this:

```
  T(n)    =   n^2  ->  T(n/4)
                   ->  T(n/2)
```

When you expand the first branch, you make a substitution `n = n/4` so you get:

```
  T(n/4)  =   (n/4)^2  ->  T((n/4)/4)
                       ->  T((n/4)/2)

          =   (n/4)^2  ->  T(n/16)
                       ->  T(n/8)
```

and similarly for the second branch, `n = n/2`

```
  T(n/2)  =   (n/2)^2  ->  T(n/8)
                       ->  T(n/4)
```

so substituting these expansions back into `T(n)` you get

```
  T(n)    =   (n^2)    ->  (n/4)^2   ->  T(n/16)
                                     ->  T(n/8)
                       ->  (n/2)^2   ->  T(n/8)
                                     ->  T(n/4)
```

Comment: @mark peters: just an out of the way question, what if the above question carried the equation, T(n) = T(n/4) + 3, what would be the recursion tree like ?